How to keep a constant surface when showing and hiding activity?
I have examined the SurfaceView documentation, it states that you need to implement SurfaceHolder.Callback to work with the surface. In this case, it is possible to work with surface only during the period between SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated() and SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed() calls.
My problem is that I am also using native code with the Vulkan API, and for example, when the user presses Home, the surface is no longer valid, which means I need to recreate my pipeline.
Is there any way to avoid this?
An example of how this is implemented in the GameActivity template class:
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (!this.mDestroyed) {
            this.mCurSurfaceHolder = holder;
            this.onSurfaceCreatedNative(this.mNativeHandle, holder.getSurface());
        }

    }

//  Here's my drawing process...    
//  And if the user presses Home, the surface disappears 

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        this.mCurSurfaceHolder = null;
        if (!this.mDestroyed) {
            this.onSurfaceDestroyedNative(this.mNativeHandle);
        }

    }

//  And this is where the pipelines have to be recreated...

I suppose one could try to implement this without using SurfaceView at all, but how...?
